# What is the shortcut for duplicating a layer to a new document?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shortcuts

In Photoshop the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> can be used to duplicate a layer or multiple layers within a document. Is there a similar shortcut to duplicate a layer to a new document?

I am aware that one can do this using the duplicate dialogue box (right-click and choose 'duplicate...'), yet this is too much of a hassle if one wants to do this for many separate layers. I can't seem to find a shortcut for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in shortcut to do this that I know of. However, it's pretty easy to define an action and assign a custom shortcut to that.

- Open the Actions panel (Window > Actions or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>)
- Click 'Create new Action'
- Name it, assign it to a set (or leave it in Default), assign a Function key
- Go to your layers panel, right-click the layer(s) you want to duplicate, select 'Duplicate...' and then choose 'New' under Document
- Click 'OK'
- Go back to the Actions panel and click 'Stop recording'

You now have an action assigned to duplicating layers to a new doc with a shortcut. In the future, all you need to do is select the layers you want to dupe and hit the assigned Function key.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have to duplicate layers duplicate them in a new document. A handy trick is that you can select whatever layers you want and drag them into the new document.

Comment: But then you first have to create a new document. Which you don't have to do with the Duplicate command.